# Xamarin Navigation.PushAsync crashing within ItemSelected

Tags: xamarin.forms

Im new to Xamarin , so please excuse my if this is an obvious one.

I created a navigation page , where the main page has a list. When an item is selected I was going to go to that page. Then able to return with the standard navigation way. The below is my main page . When the item is clicked the page is called with PushAsync(..). I see a blank screen with the return indicator in the top left. If I press on it, nothing happens  and doesnt go back to the main page. It just freezes, then a message indicating it inst responding. If I place the PushAsync() in the main body, then works fine (see in the below).

Thanks For your help

Scott.

One of the pages is simply as follows:

```
public partial class Page3:ContentPage
{
    public Page3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();       
    }
}
```

xamal page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MultiList.Page3">
<Label Text="{Binding MainText}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</ContentPage>
```

Main Page:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

   public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var listView = new ListView
        {
            RowHeight = 40
        };

        listView.ItemsSource = new MainItem[] {
            new MainItem { Name = "Page 1" ,ID= Constants.FIRST_PAGE},
            new MainItem { Name = "Page 2" ,ID= Constants.SECOND_PAGE},
            new MainItem { Name = "Page 3" ,ID= Constants.THIRD_PAGE},
        };

        listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
        listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Name");

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Children = { listView }
        };

         //Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2()); this works here as expected

        listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) => {
            var MainItem = (MainItem)e.SelectedItem;
            switch(MainItem.ID)
            {
                case Constants.FIRST_PAGE:
                                            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
                                            break;

                case Constants.SECOND_PAGE:
                                             await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
                                            break;

                case Constants.THIRD_PAGE:  await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page3());
                                            break;
            }
            this.ClearValue(ListView.SelectedItemProperty);
            listView.SelectedItem = null;


        };

    }
}
```

}

Comment: why you are doing all operations in the constructor ? there are no events and as far as i can see that all the operations are being done inside the Constructor

Comment: I suspect that you need to explicitly test for SelectedItem == null in your ItemSelected handler.  Try adding "if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;" as the first line of ItemSelected

Comment: Jason that worked, thanks. Putting the ==null in the first line fixed this. I thought the ItemSelected routine would only get called if a list entry was selected? I placed a break point on the line, and saw that straight after I selected a line the page displayed , but then went straight back into the ItemSelected() routine again (your line of code worked), why did it go back into this routine as I never selected nothing again? As Apoorv mentions I put this is a constructor, is this not the best place to put this code in the constructor? Even though it is only whats on the page?